# What code underlies the PG_GET_LATE_BINDING_VIEW_COLS sys information function?

Tags: redshift

We want to transition to late-binding views, but late-binding view metadata is not presented by some clients (workbench/J, Toad, pgcli) which makes it hard to discover column names in these views. AWS [provides](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/PG_GET_LATE_BINDING_VIEW_COLS.html) a function, PG_GET_LATE_BINDING_VIEW_COLS, to get the metadata, but we can't seem to load this into a redshift table. Are there PG sys tables storing the late-binding view columns, or what underlies this function?

Answer (score 0):

try svv_columns, it should give you what you need